# strcat Access violation writing location c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, strcat

I am getting an error reading:

> Unhandled exception at 0x5AAF40D9 (msvcr120d.dll) in Homework6_10_7.exe: >0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x006A0000.

When running this code:

```
int main()
{
//variables
const int SIZE = 30;
char first[SIZE];
char middle[SIZE];
char last[SIZE];
char full[100];
const char comma[2] = { ',', '\0'};
const char space[2] = { ' ', '\0' };
int length = 0;

//Get the user names
cout << "Enter your first name: ";
cin.getline(first, 30);

cout << "Enter your middle name: ";
cin.getline(middle, 30);

cout << "Enter your last name: ";
cin.getline(last, 30);

//Puts the given name values into the full desired format,
strcat(full, last);
strcat(full, comma);
strcat(full, space);    
strcat(full, first);
strcat(full, space);    
strcat(full, middle);

//outputs the full name array.
cout << "Welcome new user " << full << endl;

system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
```

Is there something that I'm missing? the strcat seems to be causing the problem, but I'm not sure why. 
Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `strcat(full, last);` You know `full` had better already contain a valid terminated string, right? Your's is currently indeterminate.

Comment: You have a bug. You are not using `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

`strcat` appends a copy of the source string to the destination string. The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first character of source, and a null-character is included at the end of the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.

But you don't assuredly *have* a terminating null character, because you did not zero-initialise `full`:

```
char full[100] = {};
```

You should be using a `std::string`, anyway.

Comment: Or simply add `*full = 0;` before the remaining code if you don't feel like zero filling a buffer you're about to overwrite anyway. And of course, one could also get rid of `last` entirely and just read the last name directly into `full` in the first place (since there is where it will end up anyway).

Comment: Thanks! 
Yeah i would like to just use a string but this assignment specifically calls for a cstring >< Thanks for the help though! I just added the brackets and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

when printing full string, the last char of the string is not null and that is the problem
try to add this before appending to full string like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    full[i] = '\0';
```

or you can simply do this

```
char full[100] = {};
```